# Compare two linear layers with geoprocessing tools

Tags: qgis, geometry, geoprocessing

I'd like to know how can i have in output two layers, composed by one of the two layers in input, comparing the geometry and attributes of the 2 input layers (test_1 and test_2) using geoprocessing tools of QGIS.
For example, starting from test_1 and test_2 i need to obtain 'TRUE' and 'FALSE' layers in output:
[image]

TRUE -> got from perfect geometric coincidence and the same attribute value, between test_1 and test_2.

FALSE -> got from different geometry or different attribute value, between test_1 and test_2.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Keep attention that the part A is composed by different number of records in layer test_1 and test_2.

Moreover, "test_1" = "TRUE" + "FALSE"